# Groovy conventions: Where do I put metaClass definitions?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm starting to add some Groovy classes to an existing Java web app.  (This is not a Grails app)

Is there a convention I should follow as to where I define my metaClass extensions?

Also, I've written a handful of extensions for assisting with unit tests.  Currently, these sit in the `@Before` of the base class for the tests, but I suspect there's a more obvious place I should be setting these up.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to use Groovy's naming convention for custom MetaClasses. As long as you stick to the convention (`groovy.runtime.metaclass.[package].[class]MetaClass`) and you compile the code with your application code you should be fine. Check this [posting](http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2011/11/groovy-goodness-magic-package-to-add.html) for more information. It also provides a good example.

Answer (score 0):

If it would have been a Grails app I'd say put it in `grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy`. In any other Java web application you could simply write a `ServletContextListener` implementation which triggers on web context initialization and destruction. Register the Listener in your `web.xml`.

```
public class MetaClassInitializationListener implements ServletContextListener {
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
      // do metaClass work
   }

   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
   }
}
```

For the unit tests a base class sounds reasonable to me. If you're using JUnit you could also write an implementation of [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html). You can then pick and choose to which unit test you want to apply your extensions using the [@RunWith](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) annotation.